# Javascript : scrollTo won't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Yesterday I do a autoScroll in div.
It won't work in Firefox.. It works well on Brave + Chrome (Chrome engine).However, if I scroll all the way down it will come back up by itself.
I tried to implement with animate but also impossible.

Thank you in advance

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let test = {
    id: document.getElementById('test'),
    height: document.getElementById('test').scrollHeight,
    lastNumber: -1,
    init: false
  };
  autoScroll(test)
})

function autoScroll(element) {
  self.setInterval(() => {
    if ((element.id.scrollTop !== element.height) && element.init == false) {
      element.id.scrollTo(0, element.id.scrollTop + 0.25);
    }
    if (element.lastNumber == element.id.scrollTop) {
      element.id.scrollTo(0, element.id.scrollTop - 0.25);
      element.init = true
      if (element.id.scrollTop == 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          element.init = false
        }, 5000);
      }
    }
    element.lastNumber = element.id.scrollTop
  }, 10)
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="test">
  <div class="element">test</div>
  <div class="element">test</div>
  <div class="element">test</div>
  <div class="element">test</div>
  <div class="element">test</div>
  <div class="element">test</div>
  <div class="element">test</div>
  <div class="element">test</div>
  <div class="element">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is expected behaviour? I do not see any difference between Chrome and FX

Comment: The auto scrolling in the div. In Firefox nothing happens.

Comment: It does scroll, but only to the top once the user has tried scrolling down

Comment: Absolutely and I made a code not super clean .. ^^

Comment: I don't quite understand the logic in the auto scroll. May you explain?

Comment: I have a maximum height size on my page and I can't show all my elements. My goal is to have a div that can show all its elements with a auto scroll.

Comment: I don't think Firefox likes sub-pixel scroll values? Try `element.id.scrollTop + 1` instead?

Comment: You right. However it is too fast and bug when it arrives at the bottom of the div

Comment: Then you’ll need to change the speed of the timeout. Also scrollTop can accept a config object where you can make the scroll “smooth”. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo#examples